# Issue with POST variable in php script

Tags: php, rest, post

I have written a php script for learning how to create a REST API. But there is some issue with the code that I can't figure out.

Here is the PHP script:

---

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    // Get data
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : "";
    $status = isset($_POST['status']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']) : "";

    $length = strlen($status);
    if( $length >= 10 ) {
        $json = array("status" => 1, "name" => $name, "email" => $email, "status" => $status);
    }
    else {
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error: Status too short!", "length" => $length);
    }
}

else {
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error: Request method not accepted");
}

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

---

I am calling this from Httprequester in Mozilla Firefox with the URL "http://localhost/RESTTEST.php?name=dparua&email=d.parua%40gmail.com&pwd=something&status=very%20very%20long%20status"

But this is the response I get irrespective of how long a string I pass as status.
"{"status":0,"msg":"Error: Status too short!","length":0}"

I tried changing the code to this:

---

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        $json = array("status" => 1, "name" => $_POST['name'], "email" => $_POST['email'], "status" => $_POST['status']);
}

else {
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error: Request method not accepted");
}

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

---

And posting to this modified script, this is the error message I get: 
"
**Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\RESTTEST.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: email in **C:\xampp\htdocs\RESTTEST.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: status in **C:\xampp\htdocs\RESTTEST.php** on line **5**
{"status":null,"name":null,"email":null}"

Please suggest what is wrong.

Comment: You are reading $_POST but from what i see you are passing the parameters in get request

Comment: `$_POST` is different from `$_GET`, URL parameters are pulled via `$_GET`, if you to pull it via `$_POST`, put your fields in the body part of the http request and change your content type

Comment: also just a tip, use `postman` for testing http api

Comment: I am clicking on the POST button, and this is the URL being generated when I add the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are send POST request, but your data (name, email and status) are pulled via GET
2. You are get error in PHP script because you must used mysql_connect before mysql_real_escape_string

**P.S. mysql_real_escape_string - was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

Here you will find working PHP code (but change login and password to your):

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') OR die(mysql_error());

    // Get data
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : "";
    $status = isset($_POST['status']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']) : "";

    $length = strlen($status);
    if( $length >= 10 ) {
        $json = array("status" => 1, "name" => $name, "email" => $email, "status" => $status);
    }
    else {
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error: Status too short!", "length" => $length);
    }
}

else {
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error: Request method not accepted");
}

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

After that install POSTMAN application. And try to send that request:

[image]